# How to authenticate ldap user and login on server as GUI ,it should login on server directly via GUI

Tags: authentication, ubuntu-14.04, openldap

I am new to System admin My problem is : In my department there are 30 students in 1st year and 30 students in 2nd year which are divided into two groups lets say group1 and group2 which need to login as ldap user via Ubuntu(14.04) GUI through any System connected to LAN.Every users home directory should be created on server side ,It should mount while login as GUI in ubuntu14.04, No other user should access anyone else home directory except by self.

[I don't want authenticating user to ldap-server and creating home directory on local machine ,instead I want central directory on server side,It should looks like login to server.]

Server Side : Ubuntu 14.04 
I tried [this](http://www.unixmen.com/install-openldap-in-ubuntu-15-10-and-debian-8/)   and it works fine for me.

Client side : Ubuntu14.04
I tried [this](https://www.unixmen.com/configure-linux-clients-to-authenticate-using-openldap/)  , it also works

but the issue is , this tutorial creates home directory on local machine instead of mounting server directory.I know from where it does.

I want : If i login through ldap user It should login on server via GUI not on local machine home directory.

on client side file "/var/log/auth.log"

```js
Jul 28 11:53:06 issc systemd-logind[674]: System is rebooting.
Jul 28 11:53:23 issc systemd-logind[650]: New seat seat0.
Jul 28 11:53:23 issc systemd-logind[650]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Power Button)
Jul 28 11:53:23 issc systemd-logind[650]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event4 (Video Bus)
Jul 28 11:53:23 issc systemd-logind[650]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
Jul 28 11:53:24 issc sshd[833]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul 28 11:53:24 issc sshd[833]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul 28 11:53:25 issc lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jul 28 11:53:25 issc lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Jul 28 11:53:25 issc lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Jul 28 11:53:25 issc systemd-logind[650]: New session c1 of user lightdm.
Jul 28 11:53:25 issc systemd-logind[650]: Linked /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 to /run/user/112/X11-display.
Jul 28 11:53:26 issc lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jul 28 11:53:26 issc lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Jul 28 11:53:26 issc lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "scicomp"
Jul 28 11:53:29 issc lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Please help me, i tried many tutorial online and every tutorial looks like same ,like this one.I am trying from last 2 weeks its not working.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Yep! I tried and worked for me.    
**Server Side :** Package require to install : 
$ sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server

Updated in below file like this 

abdulrahim@issc-ldap:/ldap/batch2016part2$ sudo vi /etc/exports

#/homes 198.1.10.*(fsid=0,rw,insecure,no_subtree_check,sync)
/ldap/batch2015part1/home 198.1.10.*(fsid=1,rw,insecure,no_subtree_check,sync)
/ldap/batch2015part2/home 198.1.10.*(fsid=2,rw,insecure,no_subtree_check,sync)

Exported as per below::::

abdulrahim@issc-ldap:/ldap/batch2016part2$ sudo exportfs -r

root@issc-ldap:/ldap/rnd# showmount -e 198.1.10.45

Export list for 198.1.10.45:

/ldap/batch2015part1/home

/ldap/batch2015part2/home

**On Client Side :** Package require to install : 

$ sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-client

NOW ON CLIENT SIDE  mount,permission ,ownership::::::

$ sudo gedit /etc/fstab

#####below are partition mounted from server
198.1.10.45:/ldap/batch2015part1/home    /ldap/batch2015part1/home nfs   nfsvers=3,sync 0 3
198.1.10.45:/ldap/batch2015part2/home    /ldap/batch2015part2/home nfs   nfsvers=3,sync 0 4
### or like this below
198.1.10.45:/ldap/batch2015part1/home    /ldap/batch2015part1/home nfs   noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 3
198.1.10.45:/ldap/batch2015part2/home    /ldap/batch2015part2/home nfs   noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 4

Now mount all pertition from server side as per below : :::::

$ sudo mount -a

Check mounted partion by below commands 

$ df -h
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install and configure **autofs** for this to work.  autofs will automatically mount user's home directories on the client machine from an NFS server.  I'm not sure about creating them on the server on the fly, but if it does work, you will likely need to enable the pam_mkhomedir module in the appropriate /etc/pam.d file(s), as described [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_mkhomedir)

Comment: To clarify, autofs worked for you, or you were able to get the pam_mkhomedir module to automatically create home directories on the server?

Comment: You are right ...pam_mkhomedir module require to create home directory on server side.while configuring on client side I did below things ...
sudo gedit /etc/pam.d/common-session
#add following line at bottom
session  required                                         pam_mkhomedir.so
sudo service nscd restart